# How to send pdf file to telegram bot using c#

Tags: c#, telegram

i'm new to c# .i tried following code but not worked.Someone please help me to solve this.
i want send pdf using c# post method. Thank You

```
using System.Net.Http;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var chat_id = xxxxxx; 
var text = "This is my default text";
var token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\xxx.pdf");
var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{

    
};

var urlstring = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendDocument?chat_id={1}&document={2}";
urlstring = String.Format(urlstring, token, chat_id,file);


var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);


var response = await client.PostAsync(urlstring, content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument

Parameter document is used for URL or file_id of File to send. Pass a file_id as String to send a file that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a file from the Internet, or upload a new one using multipart/form-data. More info on Sending Files .

I guess first you need to upload that file first.

Comment: Are there any reasons to write your own code to access telegram API? If no, it's better to use public packages, e.g. [TelegramBots](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot).

Comment: send pdf file to bot? Your code demonstrate that you are using bot api token to take control of the bot. probably u should modify your question to not be confused with `Telegram Client`